# Rules sometimes don't convert saved node to nid

Tags: rules

I have a strange problem with Rules. I try to set up 2-directional entity references. It works well with one content type, but fails with another. In the latter case, saved node is not converted into node when used as parameter in action like "Set data value" and Drupal tries to save it as array (which fails, of course).

So the questions is: Do you know about something (field, content type setting), which prevents Rules from properly converting saved object?

I'm using latest Rules dev from Drupal 7.

Rules export and error message can be found at https://gist.github.com/miloskroulik/898acaea40097724ff3e

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was in the entity reference field Rules were operating on (when adding value to it). The only solution I was able to come up with was to create a new field.